# Map resize only works on events

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using jquery latitude longitude plugin. My map loads partially in jquery tabs hide and show.So after R&D i found the map resize option.Map resize option only works on map events like "click","idle".. etc

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(_self.vars.map, 'idle', function () {                       
      google.maps.event.trigger(_self.vars.map, 'resize');
   });
```

I want to run above js code (map resize) on tab click.

```js
$("#tab").on("click" , function() ){
 google.maps.event.trigger(_self.vars.map, 'resize');
});
```

but google.maps.event.trigger(map,resize); is not working on tab click.It takes map object but not resizing map on tab click.Please suggest me any solution.

Thanks,

Comment: when you click the tab, are you actually resizing the map?  Or do you just want to execute your own function?  If it only happens when the map idle or click events happen, why not trigger that instead: `google.maps.event.trigger(_self.vars.map, 'idle');`

Comment: I actually execute the map resize statement on tab click.I trigger google.maps.event.trigger(_self.vars.map, 'idle'); on tab click and on idle listener i resize map. It is working now . Thank you very much for your help.